# Getting error during Laravel Raw Query execution

Tags: php, database, laravel

I am executing this query to fetch the details from different table.
If the user is exists on table then want to print the row value else space print. But not getting output properly.

```
 $users = DB::table('user_form_submission')
            ->join('recommend_email_send_by_cron', 'recommend_email_send_by_cron.user_id','=','user_form_submission.id')
            ->select('recommend_email_send_by_cron.business_id as businessId',
                'recommend_email_send_by_cron.email as email',
                'user_form_submission.id as userId',
                'recommend_email_send_by_cron.name as name',
                'recommend_email_send_by_cron.status as status',
                'recommend_email_send_by_cron.sign_in_data as sign_in_time',
                'recommend_email_send_by_cron.sent_time as mail_sent_time',
                'user_form_submission.created_at as created_at',
                'user_form_submission.form_id as formId',
                DB::raw("(CASE WHEN (select user_id from track_button_events where (recommend_email_send_by_cron.user_id = user_id) && (recommend_email_send_by_cron.business_id = business_id)) THEN 'Yes' ELSE '' END) as noButtonClicked"),
                DB::raw("(CASE WHEN (select user_id from recommend_feedback_details where (recommend_email_send_by_cron.user_id = user_id) && (recommend_email_send_by_cron.business_id = business_id)) THEN recommend_feedback_details.feedback ELSE '' END) as message"),
                DB::raw("(CASE WHEN (select user_id from recommend_yes_button_track where (recommend_email_send_by_cron.user_id = user_id) && (recommend_email_send_by_cron.business_id = business_id)) THEN 'Yes' ELSE '' END) as yesButtonClicked"),
                DB::raw("(CASE WHEN (recommend_email_send_by_cron.status= 'sent') THEN 'Yes' ELSE '' END) as mail_sent"
            )
            ->where('user_form_submission.business_id', '=', $businessId)
            ->get();

        print_r($users)
```

Error:

> Unknown column 'recommend_feedback_details.feedback' in 'field list'

Comment: Does this field `feedback` exists in `recommend_feedback_details` table?

Comment: check feedback column exist in recommend_feedback_details

Comment: Please put your full query with recommend_feedback_details.feedback and first check recommend_feedback_details table for feedback column

Comment: Yes it exists. When I am going to print the row value it gives error, but I am printing 'Yes' or string it printed

Comment: I need to check the userId is exists on different table and print the value else print "Not available" on select query.

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd  I have already put full query. In case I am printing the "Yes" on the place of  'recommend_feedback_details.feedback' then it is working fine but when I goes to put row value i.e feedback. it gives me error.

Comment: The problem is that you access the `feedback` column outside the scope of the select from that table.  If you look at how your CASE is constructed, the select is not at the same level as where you access the field.

Comment: @NigelRen Thanks for the reply, In that case, How can we achieve the "feedback" value?

Comment: I'm not a Laravel person - but you could `join()` to that table at the query level and then it should be available.